# Upright blackboard lower case greek in mtpro2

Tags: fonts, mtpro

I have yet another problem with the `mtpro2` package in LaTeX. The claim is that they have lower blackboard greek both italic and upright. However there is no way of accessing the upright version in LaTeX, in plain TeX you just use `\mhbi\upmu` for example and it works however `\mathbb{\upmu}` does not work in LaTeX.

Any ideas for a work around?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because in `mtpro2.sty`, upright math greek letters are declared as `\mathord`, but not `\mathalpha`. Thus they cannot change font by `\mathbb`.

[image]

You can redefine these letters as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mtphbi]{mtpro2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upGamma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"80}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upDelta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"81}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upTheta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"82}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upLambda}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"83}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upXi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"84}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upPi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"85}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upSigma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upUpsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"87}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upPhi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"88}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upPsi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"89}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upOmega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"7F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upalpha}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"92}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upbeta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"93}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upgamma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"94}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\updelta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"95}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upepsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"96}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upzeta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"97}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upeta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"98}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uptheta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"99}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upiota}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"9A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upkappa}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"9B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uplambda}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"9C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upmu}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"9D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upnu}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"9E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upxi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"9F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{160}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uprho}{\mathalpha}{letters}{161}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsigma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{162}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uptau}{\mathalpha}{letters}{163}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upupsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{164}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upphi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{165}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upchi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{166}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppsi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{167}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upomega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{168}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarepsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{169}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvartheta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{170}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarpi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{171}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarrho}{\mathalpha}{letters}{172}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarsigma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{173}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarphi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{174}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarkappa}{\mathalpha}{letters}{175}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarbeta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{177}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvardelta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{179}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{\pi\uppi}$

$\pi\uppi$

\end{document}
```

I didn't examine the code much. Is there any other side effect?

Comment: This does work, thank you! Is there a shorter solution even possible?

Comment: @Hesam: No, I think.

Comment: This seems to have no effect with the option `\usepackage[mtphrb]{mtpro2}` instead. Not sure why?